# jquery target input with name in last div of class

Tags: jquery

I have several div's with the class **.agrRow**.
In each .agrRow there is an input field with the name **agrNameOF**.

I want to set the value of that field.
I've tried something like:

```
$(".agrRow:last input[type='input'][name='agrNameOF']").val(fname);
```

but that doesn't work.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing `input[type='input']` to `input[type='text']` or if it can be other types too then just do `input[name='agrNameOF']`

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6tf6fbcn/**

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.agrRow input[type="text"][name="agrNameOF"]').val(fname);
```

why you use :last?

Comment: OP used `:last` to *specify the "last div of class"*, this may have been better as a comment.